# How to ignore tests when session fixture fails in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

Let's say I have a test as shown below:

```
import pytest
import copy

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def session_tool(request):
    tool = request.config.tool
    # Build is the critical part and may fail, raising an exception
    tool.build()
    return tool

@pytest.fixture
def tool(session_tool):
    return copy.deepcopy(session_tool)

def test_tool(tool, args):
    assert tool.run(args) == 0
```

It builds a session-scoped tool and then creates a copy of it for each testcase. But when the build fails, `session_tool` fixture is executed again for the next testcase, which fails again... until it fails for all testcases. As there are a lot of testcases, it takes some time until the process is finished.

Is there any way to tell pytest to skip all tests which use `session_fixture` after the first attempt to build fails?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two approaches:

1) calling [`pytest.skip()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html#skipping-test-functions) will cause the test to be skipped. This works if it's called from within a fixture as well. In your case, it will cause all the remaining tests to be skipped.

2) calling [`pytest.exit()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/builtin.html?highlight=exit#_pytest.runner.exit) will cause your test suite to stop running, as if KeyboardInterrupt was triggered.

Comment: I'm aware of the `skip` and `exit` functions, but this is not really what I wanted to achieve. My goal is to completely skip the tests, meaning that the fixture is not called ever again.

Comment: Is your goal specifically to skip the invocation of the fixture? It may be possible to do what you describe by implementing custom hooks, e.g. maybe the collection hooks would get at what you're after: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html#collection-hooks

But that's going to be much harder in my opinion. If I were you, I would wrap the build piece in an exception handler, set some relatively global flag if it blows up, and short-circuit the fixture if that flag is set.